# Sharing Contacts with Aiogram 3

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

I'm working on a Telegram bot using Aiogram 3, and I'm having trouble implementing a feature where the bot can request and receive the user's phone number. Here's the pattern of my bot:

The bot sends a welcome message along with an image.
After that, it sends an inline button "Share Contact" to the user.
When the user clicks the "Share Contact" button, I want to receive the user's phone number and print it to the console.

Here's my code:

```
import asyncio
import logging

from aiogram.filters.command import Command
from aiogram.utils.keyboard import InlineKeyboardBuilder
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
bot = Bot(token="YOUR_BOT_TOKEN")
dp = Dispatcher()

@dp.message(Command("start"))
async def start(message: types.Message):
    photo_url = 'YOUR_IMAGE_URL'

    await message.answer_photo(photo_url,
                               caption="Hello there! Here's a welcome message with an image. Good luck!")

    builder = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    builder.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(
        text="Share Contact",
        callback_data="share_contact",
        request_contact=True),
    )

    await message.answer(
        "Please share your contact with us:",
        reply_markup=builder.as_markup()
    )

@dp.callback_query(F.data == "share_contact")
async def share_contact(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    user = callback.from_user
    print("phone", callback.message.contact)
    await bot.send_message(user.id, f"User: {user}")

async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```